# Elliptic Equation with Wentzell boundary condition

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-pde, estimation-theory

I'm looking for a reference showing how to obtain a priori estimate for solutions to a linear second-order elliptic equation with Wentzell boundary condition in a bounded domain in $H^1$ space.

The problem I'm considering is
\begin{equation}\begin{cases}
Lu = \partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_j u) + b^i\partial_i u + cu & = & f &\mbox{in } \Omega \\
Bu = \alpha^{st}D_{st}u + \beta^sD_su+\gamma u & = & g &\mbox{on } \partial\Omega
\end{cases}\end{equation}

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this kind of equation should refer the relavence paper.